# Проблемы с основами ООП в Python

Tags: python, ооп, классы, методы, атрибуты

1)Создаю класс StringInOut, обладающий двумя методами:

1. getString() - метод, читающий данные из консоли
2. printUpperString() - метод, выводящий прочитанную строку в верхнем регистре

Собственно следующий код у меня есть-

```
 class StringInOut:
     arg=StringInOut()
     def getString(self,arg):
         self.arg=str(input())

     def printUpperString(self,arg):
         return self.arg.upper
```

Делаться это все должно совсем не так, но ,увы, подходящих под мой случай подсказок в интернете я не нашел.

2)Создаю класс Student, обладающий одним приватным атрибутом __ssn (целое число), который можно установить через конструктор класса.

Ну а тут я и вовсе не в курсе, что и как делать.

Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: вот вам в помощь,не нравится яндекс, можно у гугла спросить тоже самое (у яндекса внизу даже кнопочка есть)  - https://yandex.ru/search/?text=python%20%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0c%D1%81%D0%B0%20&lr=219&clid=2055854&win=107

Comment: arg должен создаваться совсем не так. Гуглите про специальный метод `__init__`. Ну и уж точно arg не должен быть экземпляром класса StringInOut, он должен быть просто строкой.

Comment: под консолью вы подразумеваете то, куда вы вводите данные при запуске программы из консоли?

Comment: @finally   Да,именно это я и имел ввиду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не до конца понял первый вопрос, однако на второй ответ у меня найдётся.

```py
class Student:
    __ssn = None  # Эту строчку, на самом деле, можно закомментировать. Расположил её здесь, чтобы показать, что у Student-а есть такое поле

    def __init__(self, input__ssn):
        self.__ssn = input__ssn  # Присваиваю полю __ssn значение input__ssn
        print("Создали нового ученика и присвоили его __ssn значение {}".format(self.__ssn))

stud_1 = Student(5)
```